# Create Membership Profile MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I'm creating an Admin page for my ASP.Net MVC 3 application.  I can create a new user, like this:

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.CreateUser(user.UserName, user.Password);
Membership.UpdateUser(mu);
```

I can assign roles like this:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(user.UserName, "Customer");
```

But how do I create and attach a new profile?

`ProfileManager` has methods to Find and Delete profiles, but no method to create one.

If it matters, I have added custom profile properties like this:

```
<properties>
  <add name="FirstName" />
  <add name="LastName" />
</properties>
```

I assume that a profile is not automatically created when the user is created, because a subsequent call to

```
ProfileInfoCollection profiles = 
    ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);
```

returns an empty collection, while `Membership.GetAllUsers()` returns the one user I just created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that I have to use `ProfileBase` to create a new profile entry:

```
ProfileBase pi = ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access the profile properties using the HttpContext.Profile property, which is available through the Controller class:

```
ViewBag.Name = HttpContext.Profile["Name"];
```

The ASP.NET framework uses the profile provider to load the profile properties for a user the first time we access the profile data and writes any modifications back through the provider at the end of the request. We don’t have to explicitly save changes; it happens automatically.